# MyFaces renderResponse - skip browser

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, jsf, myfaces

We are using MyFaces 1.1.1  My question is  -  Is it possible to skip the browser ( discard the rendered jsp) during renderResponse in jsf lifecycle and instead  send an HttpRequest  to simulate user clicking  a button in the jsp at times(say based on some 'skip' variable) ?

I am trying to see how if jsf lifecycle can somehow be changed to abandon rendering of the current page and instead simulate the click of a  button on the current page.

Comment: Strange, unusual, uncommon question. What is the actual use case?

Comment: we are processing many records and when the processed record has no errors , the  user should not be sent the rendered jsp.

Comment: Then send to a different page then....

Comment: The requirement is I dont want to show any other page, instead I want to have like a "bypass" feature in myfaces to discard the httpresponse.

Comment: Then, conditionally, return null or void in the action and you stay on the same page.

Comment: Just to experiment, where should I try to bypass the browser ( renderResponse) , discard the Httpresponse? Any ideas on this?

Comment: You don't/should not try to bypass anything, like I stated before... You make sure the browser gets the right response by explicitly sending it the right response from the managed bean. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777852/navigate-to-the-same-page-after-action-in-jsf-2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631949/how-can-i-navigate-to-another-page-in-managed-bean but maybe learn about ajax too since that seems more suitable here

Comment: Thanks. Just read - Use FacesContext#responseComplete() to signal JSF that you've already handled the response yourself and that JSF thus doesn't need to render the response. Will this help in my case ?

Comment: If you are going to manually send a pdf or textfile or excel then yes, but that does seem to be your usecase